# Grammar for $\{ a^i b^j: j < 2i \text{ and } j \ne i \} $

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

For the following language, write grammar independent of the text.

$$\{a^i b^j: j < 2i \text{ and } j \ne i \} $$

I want a hint to start solving this problem. Where should I start?

Answer (score 1):

If $j \neq i$ then either $j < i$ or $j > i$. Hence you can write your language as
$$
\{ a^i b^j : j < i \} \cup \{ a^i b^j : i < j < 2i \}.
$$
It suffices to find a grammar for each of these two languages. Such questions have been asked and answered on this site.

Comment: This site isn’t for doing your homework for you.

Comment: You are right :)